# How to create a multidimensional array of string and byte together

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, byte

I have a business requirement where my front-end mule passes me "an array containing a maximum of 10 rows, with each row containing a name and a image byte stream"

I researched and found we can create variables like below:

```
Byte[] m = new Byte[9]

String name = string.empty;
```

I want something like:

```
Input[9,9] g = new Input[9,9];
```

My data for `g` looks like:

```
g = {{ hehhdh0474637, test1}, { gsgsgh376,test2}... upto 9}
```

I’m a business analyst but doing some coding to meet my company's software requirements, so apologies if it’s a silly question -- but that’s what I want to achieve

Comment: Is it possible `each row containing a name and a image byte stream` means an object with 2 properties, one for a name as a string and one is a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is a little vague, but I'll give it a go.

I think what you want is something called a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Then you would declare it as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, Byte[]> inputs = 
            new Dictionary<string, Byte[]>();
```

You could then add key/value pairs to your dictionary like so:

```
inputs.Add(name, m);
```

You can then read / update from the dictionary with Array style syntax:

```
inputs[name] = m[x];
```

Comment: Kyle thank you so much, I think we are nailing down. I can receive upto 10 items for this. One more quick help, can you please help with how to add to this dictionary win say sample2 array of bytes and it’s name...also, once added, how would I assign to individual properties of bytes and string name both would be list I think or again array...please help with same 2 rows ?

Comment: Kyle, thank you, only your declaration is understandable for me. I dont understand other two statements or sntax...can you explain with a data for looping and reading and assigning it to individual variables

Comment: The question is a bit too vague for me to really any write more expansive code.  The Microsoft doc I linked lays out all the ways you can use a Dictionary pretty well.